# omxplayer shuffle?

Tags: audio, ls, sort, mp3, music

On my Linux machine, I am trying to shuffle all music in my directory and play it. When I run `omxplayer $(ls -1b  |sort -R)`, it says `/usr/bin/omxplayer.bin: invalid option -- '\'`. This doesn't make sense. `omxplayer` should run the output of `ls -1b` which should show the output of the directory in `1` column and show escape characters so it would recognize the spaces. What am I doing wrong and how else could I shuffle all music in my directory and play it?

Comment: Doesn't omxplayer have an inherent shuffle option?  All other media players I know have one. Try `man omxplayer | grep -i shuffle` or `omxplayer --help`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`omxplayer "$(ls | shuf -n 1)"` should work.

Comment: "might work"? what are the failure cases? (see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)